# PPT to pdf or PNG with Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, npm, powerpoint

Is there any way or any package that can convert ppt files to pdf or png without OS dependencies?
I am trying to convert a ppt file into png but all the packages require OS dependencies like LibreOffice or ImageMagick.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Aspose.Slides Cloud SDK for Node.js](https://products.aspose.cloud/slides/nodejs/) to convert presentations to PDF, PNG, and many other [formats](https://docs.aspose.cloud/slides/convert-powerpoint-documents-to-other-file-formats/#conversion-formats). The following code example shows you how to convert a PowerPoint presentation to a PDF document using Aspose.Slides Cloud:

```js
const cloud = require("asposeslidescloud")
const fs = require("fs")

const slidesApi = new cloud.SlidesApi("client_id", "client_secret")

const fileStream = fs.createReadStream("example.pptx")

// Convert the presentation to a PDF document.
slidesApi.convert(fileStream, "pdf").then((response) => {

    // Save the PDF document to a file.
    fs.writeFile("output.pdf", response.body, (error) => {
        if (error) throw error
    })
})
```

This is a paid product, but you can make 150 free API calls per month for presentation conversions and other purposes. It provides a REST-based API for managing presentations. I work as a Support Developer at Aspose.

Comment: Do you have a free solution for converting ppt to images?

Comment: Unfortunately no.